# How to switch to a frame when it is inside frameset tag

Tags: java, html, selenium

I have to handle a frame which is inside the tag frameset. While I try to switch I get the selenium exception "NoSuchFrameException".

Comment: your code and source?

Comment: If you want help with your code, you need to show us that code! Please have a read through [ask].